# Encrypting import's output with gpg at the same time

Tags: pipe, gpg

The `import` command saves screenshot in a file. Is there a way to encrypt that file at the same time using `gpg`, without saving the image file first? `gpg` accepts input from stdin but it seems that import doesn't support writing files to stdout, so I can't pipe output of the `import` to `gpg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import` command on my system supports writing to stdout.  Just use `-` as the filename.  You'll probably want to prefix that with the image format you want, e.g.:

```
import png:- | gpg ...
```